# Can a table and a column within it use the same name in Sybase?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I am using a Sybase database and would like to know if it's valid to have a table contain a column with the same name as that of the table, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
     foo      int      not null,
     etc...
)
```

Comment: Why do you ask?  Did you try it and it didn't work?  If so, was there an error?  If not, why not go try it and see?  Since the docs don't say anything about it, you should be able to, but if you're getting an error, that would be a helpful thing to add to your question.  Even if it is something that can't be done, why not just name the column something logical like FooId, so that there's less confusion.  Code clarity guidelines apply just much as reserved keywords and database-specific naming guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valid? Sure. Recommended? No.

Comment: Agreed it's not great but it's kind of specific example, I'd normally avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can surely do that but as said it is not recommended. But why are we able to do so? Well, because a table name entry goes into the system table sysobjects however column entries go in the system table syscolumns.

Therefore there is no restriction in using table name as column name, however using table name as column name usually is not recommended because it makes your table structure a bit confusing and also it adds bad practice to database design.